# $_POST is empty

Tags: php, apache-flex, apache, post

I'm posting data from a Flex app to a php script. GET works fine but POST doesn't seem to transmit anything. as3httpclintlib is the library I'm working with, however, I kind of doubt that is the problem, because replicating the request in php gives me the same result. I've looked around and while there seem to be multiple issues similar to this, none of the proposed suggestions worked.

My php.ini looks good from what I can tell, however I did recently recompile Apache and PHP.

```
//php.ini
...
variables_order = "EGPCS"
register_globals = off
register_argc_argv = On
post_max_size = 8M
gpc_order = "GPC"
...
```

the request body is pretty simple:

```
data={\"id\":0,\"password\":\"abcdefg\",\"name\":\"testUser\",\"createdOn\":null,\"apikey\":\"hijklmn\"}
```

it looks weird w/ all the slashes, but I stripslashes() and it works fine... usually.

So, it's not Flash, because a request from PHP acts the same way. It's not the request -- seemingly -- because an identical GET works fine, Content-Type is set to **'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'**. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the recent compilation but that's about as far as I have been able to take it. Thank you for any suggestions.

Apache 2.2
PHP 5.3.3

**UPDATE**: Still haven't gotten it working, but it looks like it might be apart of my Apache configuration. I didn't think anything I did was substandard, but I am not seeing many other solutions. Is there anything in particular I should look for to check against my config?

**UPDATE 2**: After recompiling Apache and PHP with only the required modules and extensions it worked fine. I had some extra stuff loaded for future use, perhaps.... perhaps it was one of those that was throwing things off.

Comment: Are you actually performing a POST http request from your flex app?

Comment: yes, and have verified it by request headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with PHP 5.3.2 Suhosin-Patch and a htaccess file overriding:

```
php_value post_max_size = 150M
```

Here is a one line workaround :

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_POST);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your request body parameters should be URL encoded (maybe it is but you decoded it for readability?). Secondly, check the magic_quotes_gpc setting in php.ini, it may make a difference.

Lastly, you can check if the POST actually works by reading the raw POST data:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: my response in php looks like:

print_r($_POST);
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];

and I get:

Array
(
)
application/x-www-form-urlencoded

back out of it. So nothing is coming through php://input. my ini file has magic_quotes_gpc = On. I imagine that's correct?

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated, as it can't be relied on. It's On by default in 5.2, but Off by default in 5.3. It may be causing you problem. It should always be disabled in my opinion. You can read more on magic_quotes_gpc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Answer (score 0):

If all else fail, try this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

If this is the problem, either fix Mod Security of your Apache, or disable it for that script.

Comment: didn't seem to make a difference. I even tried SecFilterEngine Off.

Comment: no wonder it didn't make a difference, I removed it yesterday when I recompiled Apache.

Comment: What happens when you post something from a standard `<form method="post" ...` form?

Comment: it seems like a recompilation of Apache and PHP did the trick. I went through and refined the modules and extensions I had.